# Normal approximation for sum of dependent indicators from triangular array

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Suppose there is a triangular array of random variables $X_{k,n}$ with the following properties:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{k,n} = 1) = p_n, \quad \mathbb{P}(X_{k,n} = 0) = 1 - p_n, 
\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}p_n = p > 0,\\
\mathrm{cov}(X_{i,n}, X_{j,n}) = \begin{cases}
c_n \neq 0, & |i - j| \leq 1, \\
d_n, & |i - j| > 1.
\end{cases}, \quad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{cov}(X_{i,n}, X_{j,n}) = \begin{cases}
c \neq 0, & |i - j| \leq 1, \\
0, & |i - j| > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
To be exact, $d_n$ decays as $O(n^{-1})$.

Let's define $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_{k,n}$, $\mu_n = \mathbb{E}S_n$ and $\sigma_n^2 = \mathrm{var}S_n$. It's also known that $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n^2$ are both $O(n)$. From numerical simulations, I can see that $\frac{S_n - \mu_n}{\sigma_n}$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

I'm looking for a reference to some version of Central Limit Theorem for this setup. I'm not sure if given properties are enough to prove the convergence, so having a theorem that requires additional facts about dependence is fine as well.

Comment: Are the rows independent?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis yes

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis It's about independent random variables and is a sufficient condition for Lindeberg-Feller CLT to hold and Lindeberg-Feller theorem is for triangular arrays of independent random variables. Here, the $Var(S_{n})=O(n)$ and $X_{k,n}$ and $X_{k\pm 2,n}$ are only asymptotically independent.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0865-5_9) will help. This is from the collected works of Hoeffding.